# get correct word from wrong word php

Tags: php, spell-checking, linguistics

i want to know how to get correct word from wrong one...

example

The string is "sstring"

but the correct word is string...

is any algorithm in php?

thanks and advance

Comment: Why is (was, I changed it) this tagged as `array`?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be accessing the Google spellchecker API.

There are also local solutions which just require a dictionary file. Googling for 'php spellchecker' will give you tons of possible solutions.